# If we remove half the samples from an IID dataset, is the remaining half still IID?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, sampling, iid

I am generating 10,000 pairs of `X` and `Y` such that both `X` and `Y` are standard normal and IID, and I'm storing them pairwise in a variable called `Z`:

```
import numpy as np
m=10000
k=2
Z = np.random.normal(0,1,(m,k)) # Mean=0, Std_Dev=1
```

Now, I remove those pairs with `x+y>0`, so I'm left with a new set of `{x,y}` with `x+y<=0`:

```
Z_new = []
for i in range(len(Z)):
    if Z[i][0]+Z[i][1] <= 0:
        Z_new.append(Z[i])
```

The question is, **are `X` and `Y` in this new set, `Z_new`, still independent?**

---

To analyze this, I stored the original and new `X` and `Y` and plotted them:

```
X_orig = []
Y_orig = []
for i in range(len(Z)):
    X_orig.append(Z[i][0])
    Y_orig.append(Z[i][1])

X_new = []
Y_new = []
for i in range(len(Z_new)):
    X_new.append(Z_new[i][0])
    Y_new.append(Z_new[i][1])
```

Here's the plot of the original `X` and `Y`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(X_orig, Y_orig)
plt.xlabel('Original X')
plt.ylabel('Original Y')
plt.show()
```

[image]

And here's the plot of the new `X` and `Y`:

```
plt.scatter(X_new, Y_new)
plt.xlabel('New X')
plt.ylabel('New Y')
plt.show()
```

[image]

So, I can see that the correlation between the original `X` and `Y` is close to 0 while the correlation between the new `X` and `Y` is close to -0.5. But, how do I conclude about the IID-ness of the new `X` and `Y` from this?

If I were to guess from "common sense", I would think that yes, the remaining sample should still be IID. That's because, the process with which the values were generated did not take any relationship between the values or pairs into account, so they are purely random values. So, even though there's negative correlation between the remaining `X` and `Y`, that should not change the IID-ness of it. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: This is accept reject 101 : you have generated iid realisations of the bivariate normal restricted to the half-space.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what "accept reject 101" means. Could you please elaborate a bit more, if you don't mind? I don't have statistics background, so trying to think, learn and understand the concepts from the ground up.

Comment: Ok, so the remaining half of the samples are IID, and my reasoning is correct, am I right?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ would be identically distributed but clearly are not independent, for example since a positive value of $X$ precludes a positive value of $Y$

Comment: @Henry: I think the question is about the $(X_i,Y_i)$'s being iid, which is correct.

Comment: Note that the title is incorrect in that you do not remove exactly half of the sample.

Comment: @Xi'an You may be correct, in that $(X_i,Y_i)$ is independent of $(X_j,Y_j)$ for $i \not=j$ in this conditional case, while $X_i$ is not independent of $Y_i$

Comment: One glance at your (very effective) scatterplot answers the question.  *Obviously* the new variables are not independent, because the conditional distribution of one depends on the value of the other.